# Deserialize error with Jackson (png encoding)

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have following string to parse (string to object) :

```
{   "langues" : 
    [
        {"iso":"en", "id":1, "flag":[0,144,255,62,1,152,84,62,1,104,50,63,1,32,90,61,1,172,110,66,1,216,...]}
        ,
        {"iso":"fr", "id":2, "flag":[0,208,0,63,1,208,106,62,1,120,49,63,1,32,90,61,1,60,110,...]}
        ,
        { etc... }
    ],
    "when" : 133111... // timestamp
}
```

The `flag` is an array of byte for a png image

And following objects :

```
public class Langues {
    private Long when;
    private ArrayList<Langue> langues;

    public Long getWhen(){ return when; }
    public void setWhen(Long when) { this.when=when; }
    ...
}

public class Langue {
    private int id;
    private String iso;
    private byte[] flag;

    // getters / setters
}
```

this throw me an error :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Langues node = mapper.readValue(myString, Langues.class);
```

`JsonParseException`

```
Numeric value (144) out of range of Java byte
```

maybe byte[] is not the right container for it or can i set jackson parser encoding somewhere ?

thanks in advance !!

`[EDIT]`

maybe editing each field of the array of byte with -128 could have done it but kind of tricky and a real waste of time...

i contacted codehaus thanks to mailing list and i ended in no time with an AnsiString instead of UNICODE or Bytes, and voilà !

```
{"langues":[{"iso":"zh","id":7,"flag":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAABpCAYAAADy...
```

with same simple code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Langues node = mapper.readValue(myString, Langues.class);
```

Comment: Is `Langue` a publicly accessible class? I once had an error like this and the problem was I declared a private class instead of it being public. What are the getters and setters?

Comment: `Langue` and `Langues` are public class in their own java files with simple getters and setters like `public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }` that's all

Comment: Please add the error/exception you get -- without that it is hard to know what is happening. For what it is worth, except JSON type for byte[] is actually Base64-encoded String. However, actual array of integers should also work (if not, submit a bug report?)

Comment: my array is made of unsigned bytes and java expects signed bytes. i made an AnsiString  Base64 encoded and it's wonderfully fast... that's all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe editing each field of the array of byte with -128 could have done it but kind of tricky and a real waste of time...

i contacted codehaus thanks to mailing list and i ended in no time with an AnsiString instead of UNICODE or Bytes, and voilà !

```
{"langues":[{"iso":"zh","id":7,"flag":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAABpCAYAAADy...
```

with same simple code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Langues node = mapper.readValue(myString, Langues.class);
```